# Analogue of Borel transform for holomorphic functions

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, analysis, summation-method

Let $f$ be holomorphic at $z_0$, and therefore agrees with its Taylor series in a neighbourhood around $z_0$,
$$f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(z_0)}{n!}(z-z_0)^n. $$
Is there an (integral) transform $\tilde f$ of $f$, with the property that
$$\tilde f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(z_0)}{n!(n+1)!}(z-z_0)^n?$$
In other words, is there an analytic relationship between a holomorphic function with derivatives $f^{(n)}$ and one with derivatives $f^{(n)}/(n+1)!$? I am aware of the Borel transform, which would give a relation for an additional $n!$ inserted rather than $(n+1)!$.

Comment: For $|z|< r$ try $$\int_{|s|=r} f(z_0+s) \frac{\exp(z/s)-1}{z/s}\frac{ds}{2i\pi s}$$

Comment: Thank you, I have posted the motivation in a new question, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4375049/600723. I would be very grateful for any ideas.